# Storm topology deployment failing with IllegalArgumentException when storm client upgraded from 0.10 to 1.1.0

Tags: upgrade, apache-storm

Recently, we upgraded our storm version from 0.10 to 1.1.0 but while deploying topology with the upgraded client, it was failing with -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.storm.hack.shade.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.hack.shade.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.hack.shade.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.hack.DefaultShader.addRemappedClass(DefaultShader.java:182)
    at org.apache.storm.hack.DefaultShader.shadeJarStream(DefaultShader.java:103)
    at org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer.transform(StormShadeTransformer.java:35)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.ClientJarTransformerRunner.main(ClientJarTransformerRunner.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue came out to be related to `dependency conflicts between asm and guice over Java8`. Excluding all guice dependencies which were coming from a dependent jar but wasn't actually used in storm project helped resolve this issue.

To be on safer side, I also cross-checked in my project that I do not have any other `asm` dependency except one coming from `storm-core`.

I spent more than a day to come to this resolution, hope this could be of help to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

For us that issue was that we had

```
client.jartransformer.class : org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer
```

in our storm.yaml. Removing this line fixed the issue.